# OS X application with splitted view

Tags: xcode, macos, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

Sorry for the noob question, but I'm trying to make an application with a splitted view. I created a new project, edit the *Main.storyboard*, delete the default view controller and add a *Vertical split view controller*:

[image]

I also have the following warning:

> Window Controller requires a content view controller.

My question is how can I make this *Vertical split view controller* the main view controller of my window?

Comment: Make it the starting point of your app.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Drag the storyboard entry point arrow to your navigation controller.

Comment: If I do that, I no longer have a window that pop up when I start the app. I also noticed that I have the following warning: `Window Controller requires a content view controller.`

Comment: I finally solved the problem by right clicking the window controller and linked graphically the window content segues to the split controller. I'm facing a new problem: when launching the application it pop a windows with only few pixel width... (window height is fine which lead to a weird UI)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by letting the original *View Controller* as the content of the *Window Controller*, add a *Container View* inside, and control click drag to make this *Container View* contains my *Splitter Controller View*.